# Android MediaRouteButton is Disabled

Tags: android, fragment, chromecast

I know there are similar/related post on this but doesnt get a working answer.

I am developing an app with Google Chromecast feature.
**The cast is working just fine until I add the mini controller fragment, which makes MediaRouteButton disabled.**

I am currently following [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android#6) by Google.

Here's the mini controller fragment layout.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/cast_mini_controller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:castShowImageThumbnail="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment" />
```

Any idea/help is appreciated.